# Simple File Output for mbox.txt

Tags: python

I am stuck on an assignment in high school python, and I am running short on time to finish it. I would very much appreciate a complete and working (syntax correct) piece to compare and edit my code from.

The assignment reads:
Write a program that opens and reads mbox.txt, looking for lines that contain an e-mail address, counts the number of e-mail addresses found, and prints all of them, using only one line at a time, to an output file.

Link to mbox.txt can be found here: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt

Thanks a ton!

```py
import re

name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox.txt"
handle = open(name)

email_matches = []
found_emails = []
final_emails = []
counts = dict()

for lines in handle :
    # look for specific characters in document text
    if lines.find('@') : continue
    # increments the count variable for each match I found
    lines.split()
    # appends the required lines to the matches list
    email_matches.append(lines)

for email in email_matches :
    out = email
    found = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  out)
    found_emails.append(found)

for item in found_emails :
    count = item[0]
    final_emails.append(count)

for items in final_emails:
    counts[items] = counts.get(items,0) + 1

maximum = max(counts, key = lambda x: counts.get(x))
print (maximum, counts[maximum])
```

Comment: You might wanna post the code you have so far.

Comment: Please show us your current attempt at the problem.

Comment: Trying to upload my code

Comment: I know this is probably a mess, I just need to find the emails by looking for the character '@' in a line.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code，it's dirty but seems works. Just for your reference.

```
import re

# name = input("Enter file:")
# if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox.txt"


email_matches = []
found_emails = []

# read mbox.txt file
with open("mbox.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines() :
        line = line.strip()
        # look for specific characters in document text
        if '@' in line :
            # increments the count variable for each match I found
            sentence_split_by_space = line.split()
            for one_sentence in sentence_split_by_space:
                # in case more than one email in one line
                if '@' in one_sentence:
                    # appends the required lines to the matches list
                    email_matches.append(one_sentence)

# print(email_matches)

for email in email_matches :
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  email):
        found_emails.append(email)
        print(email)

print("Total counts: ", len(found_emails))

# write results to txt file
with open('mbox_count_emails.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Total counts: ' + str(len(found_emails)) + '\n')
    for one_email in found_emails:
        f.write(one_email + '\n')
```